# css: is that possible to move texts between divs through css?

Tags: css

Html:

```
<div id="id1">
this is my text1.
</div>
<div id="id2">
this is my text2.
</div>
```

css:

```
<style>
#id1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    background-color:#00FFCC;   
}
#id2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    background-color:#FFCCCC;

}
</style>
```

In front, it shows:

```
this is my text1. (green background)
this is my text2. (pink background)
```

Now if I want it show like this:

```
this is my text1.                                   this is my text2. (green background) 
empty in pink background
```

so if do not change html codes, is that possible to make it happen only through css? Basically what i want to do is to move text:`this is my text2.` to the first div:`<div id="id1"></div>`

Comment: Move visibly, or actually change the content?

Comment: Do you want the change on load or some event like hover or click. Be specific.

Comment: That's impossible with css. This could only be accomplish using javascript or XSLT.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with css only? +1 for interesting question.

Comment: This is not a interesting question. If I say "I want to do sql operations using css. " would that be interesting question?

Comment: This can be achieved but you need to add a attribute in your html code and use `content` css property. The result will be like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QnJTZ/.  I am not sure about the compatibility of the solution though.

Comment: @Mr_Green - I think the question alone is not interesting but when answered it might be cause I'm convinced it will help a lot of people.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld it is ofcourse possible. but not with just css. Anyway I tried it and added as comment above. It is working properly. you might want to modify it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS allow to change style, but not content: Moving text between divs is not possible with CSS.

You should check other technologies like XSLT for that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ubodar/1/edit), add below CSS:

```
#id1:after {
  content:'this is my text2'; 
  margin-right:0px;
  float:right;
  background-color:#FFCCCC;
}
```

Comment: Hey how can the OP know the text? you are keeping the text in `content` css property..

Answer (score 0):

CSS is only a way of styling html elements. You cannot manipulate the content of an element through CSS, only how it is displayed. There might be a way you can make it 'seem' to have this behaviour, but the content will always be in the div they were originally in. Using javascript, this would be much easier to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move from this:

```
<div id="id1">
this is my text1.
</div>
<div id="id2">
this is my text2.
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div id="id1">
this is my text1.
this is my text2.
</div>
<div id="id2">
</div>
```

You could use javascript maybe? I don't think it's possible in CSS only, because you are editing the html in here by moving the text from one div to other one.

But you could move the second div by CSS positioning with a hover event or something like that. But that would be just change of how it looks but the text would be still in the second div.

That could be like this for example: http://jsfiddle.net/yNCk4/4/
Not best idea just showing way how it is possible.

HTML

```
<div id="id1">
this is my text1.
</div>
<div id="id2">
    <div class="text">this is my text2.</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.text:hover {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0px;
    margin 0;
}
```

So what do you want to do?

Comment: He does't want any changes in HTML!

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you can't actually move content in the dom with css alone. But you can always position the divs so you get the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do sth like that:

```
#id1:hoover{
visibility: hidden;

}
#id2:after {
  content:'this is my text1. this is my text2.'; 
  visibility: visible;
}
```

with some action hoover or some js the clue is content: to change div's text I hoper it helps.